# How are audio tracks finalized in the cinema industry?

Tags: sound, cinema, industry, final

I was wondering how exactly audio is finalized in the cinema industry.

Are they rendered in stems or a in a single audio track and then imported in a video editing software (Final Cut, Premiere, Media Composer) for a final re-rendering?

If yes, are there any precautions for this final rendering step?

Answer (score 4):

The channels of the respective output format (2.0 / 5.1 etc) are exported as separate mono audio files. Usually the encoders (DCP / Blu-ray Etc.) expect separate audio tracks as input.

Apart from that a cinema mix needs to be mixed in a certain dynamic range similar to ebu r128. Check I.e. this video for an introduction:

AFAIK the term "stem" refers to separate exports of the elements that together form the mix (voice-over, music, sfx etc.) to make further edits easier (shortened versions, international versions) without making a new entire mix.